# How to pass props from children to parent in Next.js + Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-props

I'm building a small app for my school project using Next.js and want to pass data from children to parent. I've watched and applied whats taught in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/BtImABK_VHo?t=127) but getting a TypeScript error. As seen from the code below, I'm trying to get some props from the parent, rendering some jsx and returning some value stored in a useState to the parent. I also plan to use this component many times in the app. Even though I think I'm doing it right, i get an error that says...

```
Type '({ placeholderB, placeholderH, createButton, deleteButton, updateButton, maxLengthB, maxLengthH, }: Props) => IButtonOptions' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'.

  Type 'IButtonOptions' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)
```

**ButtonOptions.tsx (child)**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
interface Props {
    placeholderB?: string;
    placeholderH?: string;
    createButton?: boolean;
    deleteButton?: boolean;
    updateButton?: boolean;
    maxLengthB?: number;
    maxLengthH?: number;
}
interface IButtonOptions {
    render: () => JSX.Element;
    createBody: string;
    createHeader: string;
    updateBody: string;
    updateHeader: string;
}
const ButtonOptions: React.FC<Props> = ({
    placeholderB,
    placeholderH,
    createButton,
    deleteButton,
    updateButton,
    maxLengthB,
    maxLengthH,
}): IButtonOptions => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [isCreate, setIsCreate] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isDelete, setIsDelete] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [createBody, setCreateBody] = useState<string>("");
    const [createHeader, setCreateHeader] = useState<string>("");
    const [updateBody, setUpdateBody] = useState<string>("");
    const [updateHeader, setUpdateHeader] = useState<string>("");

    // some code 1
    return {
        createBody,
        createHeader,
        updateBody,
        updateHeader,
        render: (
            <>
      // some code 2
            </>
        ),
    };
};

export default ButtonOptions;
```

**NewForumQuestion.tsx (parent)**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import ButtonOptions from "../../../_buttonOptions";
const NewForumQuestion: React.FC = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const { render, createBody, createHeader, updateBody, updateHeader } =
        ButtonOptions({});
    return (
        <>
            <section className={styles.outerNewQuestion}></section>
            <ButtonOptions />
        </>
    );
};

export default NewForumQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another and more efficient way. Instead of passing props from child to parent just to get the data (from the child) and execute a form action in the parent, I've made it so that you only have to pass a function from the parent to child that just does the form action and that's it. In the code below, I removed the update and delete for simplicity but one can also just define a `axios.delete()` and `axios.put()` in a function, pass it to the child and add an onSubmit

**NewForumQuestion.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import ButtonOptions from "../../../_buttonOptions";
import { axios } from "../../../../_operations/axios/axios";
const NewForumQuestion: React.FC = () => {
    const thisAPI = "/api/school-forum";
    async function CreateExecutor(
        body?: string,
        header?: string
    ): Promise<void> {
        await axios.post(thisAPI, {
            body,
            header,
        });
        return void 0;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <ButtonOptions
                createExecutor={CreateExecutor}
                createButton={true}
                placeholderH={">>> Enter Forum Question Header"}
                placeholderB={">>> Enter Forum Question Body"}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default NewForumQuestion;
```

**ButtonOptions.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
interface Props {
    createExecutor: (body?: string, header?: string) => Promise<boolean | void>;
    placeholderB?: string;
    placeholderH?: string;
    createButton?: boolean;
    deleteButton?: boolean;
    updateButton?: boolean;
    maxLengthB?: number;
    maxLengthH?: number;
}
const ButtonOptions: React.FC<Props> = ({
    createExecutor,
    placeholderB,
    placeholderH,
    createButton,
    deleteButton,
    updateButton,
    maxLengthB,
    maxLengthH,
}) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [isCreate, setIsCreate] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isDelete, setIsDelete] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [createBody, setCreateBody] = useState<string>("");
    const [createHeader, setCreateHeader] = useState<string>("");
    const [updateBody, setUpdateBody] = useState<string>("");
    const [updateHeader, setUpdateHeader] = useState<string>("");

    useEffect((): void => {
        setIsActive(false);
        return void 0;
    }, [isCreate]);


    function clearCreate(): void {
        setCreateBody("");
        setCreateHeader("");
        return void 0;
    }

    async function handleCreate(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> {
        e.preventDefault();
        await createExecutor(createBody, createHeader);
        clearCreate();
        return void 0;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <button
                type="button"
                title="Toggle Actions"
                className={styles.actionToggleButton}
                onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
            >
                <i
                    className="icon-minus-circled"
                    style={{ display: isActive ? "block" : "none" }}
                ></i>
                <i
                    className="icon-plus-circled"
                    style={{ display: isActive ? "none" : "block" }}
                ></i>
            </button>

            {/* Buttons */}
            {/* Buttons */}
            {/* Buttons */}
            {isActive && createButton && (
                <button
                    type="button"
                    title="Toggle Create"
                    className={styles.createButton}
                    onClick={() => setIsCreate(!isCreate)}
                >
                    <i className="icon-paper-plane"></i>
                </button>
            )}



            {/* Options */}
            {/* Options */}
            {/* Options */}

            <div
                className={styles.outerOptionsDivs}
                style={{ height: isCreate ? "100%" : "0px" }}
            >
                <form method="post" className={styles.optionForms} onSubmit={handleCreate}>
                    <h2 className={styles.optionH2Header}>Option Create</h2>
                    <hr className="horizontalRuleYellow" />
                    {placeholderH && (
                        <textarea
                            placeholder={placeholderH}
                            minLength={10}
                            maxLength={maxLengthH}
                            className={styles.questionTextAreaH}
                            onChange={(
                                e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
                            ) => setCreateHeader(e.currentTarget.value)}
                            value={createHeader}
                        ></textarea>
                    )}
                    <textarea
                        placeholder={placeholderB}
                        minLength={10}
                        maxLength={maxLengthB}
                        className={styles.questionTextAreaB}
                        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
                            setCreateBody(e.currentTarget.value)
                        }
                        value={createBody}
                    ></textarea>
                    <div className={styles.optionButtons}>
                        <button type="reset" onClick={clearCreate}>
                            Clear Fields
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit">Execute Option</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default ButtonOptions;
```